# Elasticsearch regexp not marching but the regexp pattern is correct

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

```
"regexp": {
  "commonStructure": {
    "value": "[^>]*?[,<]PRP[,>][^\\<]*?\\s[^>]*?[,<]VERB[,>].*",
    "flags": "ALL"
  }
}
```

The pattern is correct and its working in js and python

And her is the example string

```
<PRP,PRON>{I} <VBD,VERB>{worked} <ADVPL,IN,ADP>{in} <NNP,PROPN>{London} <IN,ADP>{at} <ADVTMRI,RB,ADV>{first} <PUNCT>{,} <CC,CCONJ>{but} <PR,PRON>{it} <VBD,VERB>{was} <RB,ADV>{not} <JJ,ADJ>{easy} <TO,PART>{to} <VB,VERB>{make} <NN,NOUN>{money} <ADVPL,RB,ADV>{there} <PUNCT>{.}
```

In this pattern, I want to get all records that have first `[PRON]` and the next neighbor is the `[VERB]`

note that in this pattern with first `[PRON]` i can pass also the word in this case {I}

Comment: If the regex works in Python and JS, it does not mean it will work in other regex flavors. `\s` is not supported by the Lucene regex engine. Try `"[^>]*[,<]PRP[,>][^\\<]*[ \t\r\n][^>]*[,<]VERB[,>].*"`. BTW, what did you match with `[^\\<]`?

Comment: Here is the supported regexp syntax for Lucene: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html#regexp-syntax

Comment: Tanks @WiktorStribiżew jan your suggestion is really helpful and its fixed my issue,
But it's so strange that `\s` isn't working in regex

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  `[^\\<]` it is a typo  from copy-pasting it must be `[^\<]` and yes I know that the correct one is `[^<]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I Tink this sone about you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IB7s3YlbU9U

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucene regex engine does not support common NFA regex shorthand character classes.

To match a whitespace, you may use your own bracket expression like `[ \t\r\n]`, or `[ \f\n\r\t\v]`.

To match any char but `<`, use `[^<]`, do not escape `<` as it is not a special regex char.

So, you may use

```
"[^>]*[,<]PRP[,>][^<]*[ \t\r\n][^>]*[,<]VERB[,>].*"
```